# Uncaught Error: No define call in require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I am a newbie with `backbone.js` and `require.js`, I still not clear of how to use `require.js`. Now I'm trying to use `require.js` with `Jquery Reveal`.

This is my `main.js` :

```
requirejs.config({
     enforceDefine: true,
     paths: {
    "jquery": "libs/jquery/jquery-min",
    "underscore": "libs/underscore/underscore-min",
    "backbone": "libs/backbone/backbone-min",
    "jquery.reveal":"libs/jquery/jquery.reveal"

    },
   shim: {
    "underscore": {
        deps: [],
        exports: "_"
    },
    "backbone": {
        deps: ["jquery", "underscore"],
        exports: "Backbone"
    },
    "jquery.reveal": ["jquery"]
   }
});
define(["jquery", "underscore", "backbone","jquery.reveal"],
  function ($, _, Backbone,Jquery_Reveal) {
    console.log("reveal " + typeof Jquery_Reveal);

  }
);
```

app.js :

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'router',
'jquery.reveal'

 ], function($, _, Backbone,Router,Reveal){

    var initialize = function(){
    Router.initialize();
 };

return {
    initialize: initialize
};

});
```

Then I got an error in chrome console : `Uncaught Error: No define call for reveal`.

Comment: have You tried adding exports to jquery reveal shim?

Comment: @Blacksonic: Not yet, and also don't know what should I export with it.

Comment: "jquery" : { exports : "$" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found and it works for me:

```
"reveal": {
   deps: ["jquery"],
   exports: "jQuery.fn.reveal"
}
```